# c++ function arguments with MATLAB syntax?

Tags: c++, matlab, function, arguments

Comming from MATLAB, I would like to know if there is a way to use function arguments in c++ like it is done in MALTAB. Here is an example to illustrate, what I am trying to use in c++:

```
draw('shape','circle','radius',5); // should draw a circle
draw('shape','square','width',3,'hight',4); // should draw a square
```

The function above is the same, but the function arguements differ. I would like to use this syntax in c++. Is there a good way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Is this really what you want? C++ has much cleaner solutions available, where you do not depend on strings, such as polymorphism. One advantage is that you will get compile-time errors in case of a coding mistake, rather than runtime errors. And your IDE will like you for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following (albeit it's not really clear what your main intention is):

```
void MyDrawingFunc(const std::vector<std::string>& Arguments)
{
    auto& arg = Arguments[0];

    if (arg == "shape")
        DoShapeStuff(Arguments); // use Arguments[1...]
    else if (arg == "otherThing")
           ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make c++ work exactly like MATLAB (see answer above), but it doesn't make too much sense. A very good indication for that is your test case itself:

```
draw('shape','square','width',3,'hight',4); // should draw a square
```

You misspelt `height`. In my usual code you would be getting (runtime) warning of "unknown specifier `hight`" and having 4 ignored in favor of default value or perhaps doing nothing. And this warning is here only because I bother writing it in `otherwise` block. A lot of coworkers' code doesn't, and would just silently use default value or not do anything.

Now try debugging that in the middle of a complicated `find some elements on image` function - you wouldn't easily figure out it is a simple typo in your call to `draw` function.

So, instead of making Matlab code in c++, you should write something like:

```
void MyDrawingFunct(Shape shape){
...}

void MyDrawingFunct(Curve curve){
...}
```

Where you would draw shapes you have defined (like square, circle etc), and another function for curves etc. Or, if you want to safeguard against say adding `Ellipse` to `Shape` and have it fail at runtime, you can have some more functions - `...(Square ...)` etc.

The main benefit is that trying to call `MyDrawingFunct` with say `Ellipsoid` will immediately notify you of error (at compile time), while doing things your usual MATLAB way will have you wondering whether `ellipsoid` is not implemented or you just made a typo somewhere (like in your example). And you will hit that at runtime.